# How can I prevent double binding on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my situation, I have a table which can add/remove rows dynamically and I need to bind the remove row when the page loads.

Here's my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 $(".btnRemoveRow").bind("click", removeRow); });
 </script>
```

But I also need to Bind another removeRow when I add rows here's on my external js

```
function addRow(){ 
{--add row code here--}
$(".btnRemoveRow").bind("click", removeRow); 
}
```

so that the newly added rows will also be bind with the removeRow function,

here is my removeRow function:

```
function removeRow(){

var row = $(this).closest('tr');
var selected = row.find('input.qty,input.price,textarea,select').val();
$.getScript("calculate.js", function(){});

if(selected)
{
var r=confirm("Confirm Remove?");
if (r==true)
{

  row.find('input.qty,input.price,textarea,select').attr("disabled", true);
  row.find('input.hidden-deleted-id').val("yes");
  row.find('.subtotal>center>h3').text("0");
  calculate();

  row.hide();
  return false;
}
else
{
  return false;
} 
}

else{

  row.find('input.qty,input.price,textarea,select').attr("disabled", true);
  row.find('input.hidden-deleted-id').val("yes");
  row.find('.subtotal>center>h3').text("0");
  calculate();
  row.hide();
  return false; 
  }

  };
```

Case 1: when I remove row without adding any rows first, it works fine (dialog box only appears once).

Case 2: when I add row first then remove the rows that were already bound on the page ready, dialog box appears twice.

Case 3: when I remove rows that I added, it works fine (dialog appears once).

(PS: still learning JavaScript)

Any idea how may I solve case no.2 please?

Comment: Look into using `event delegation`

Comment: There is also `off()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one event handler that is delegated, that way it will work for existing elements, and future elements

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(document).on("click", ".btnRemoveRow", removeRow); 
 });
</script>
```

replace `document` with the closest non-dynamic parent element.

Comment: that was a quick one.

Comment: Thanks @amenadiel It worked! Ive been squeezing my head for many days for that bug hahaha it was just a simple fix! thanks to you!

Comment: @melvnberd If possible, do consider to reduce the scope of the delegation; adding a click handler on `document` handles ALL clicks, a common parent element is recommended.

Comment: Hi @Jack Thank you for your advice! though I cant really get it yet, I'll try search for it and apply it on my codes :) I really appreciate advices :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){ 
   $(".btnRemoveRow").click(function(){removeRow();});
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Aways welcome! @melvnberd. I like this way because it really quick and clear. Sorry about my English, so I can't explain it so far :D.